# How to search a custom list in webpart using Visual Studio?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a custom list in a webpart. I need to search that list based on some filter conditions. How can we do that using visual studio code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume, based on your question, that you are new to SharePoint development. So, the first step is to spend some time to understand the fundamentals - here's a video that will help you get started. It's for SharePoint 2010 but most of the material applies to SharePoint 2013 as well.

[SharePoint 2010 for ASP.NET Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=an1IkFzHpBk)

Then you want to take a look at how to build web parts:

[Creating Web Parts for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx)

Then you can move on to what you need to do to query the list. In SharePoint, this is done using a CAML query.

[SPList.GetItems method (SPQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx)

[Query Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521.aspx)

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I'm new to sharepoint.(2 months) :)